# Xamarin.IOS does not receive firebase notifications but registers fcmToken

Tags: ios, firebase, xamarin, firebase-cloud-messaging

Hello I need some suggestions what may be the reason why my notifications are sent but I never receive them on my phone, also its debugged on physical device -> iPhone X (14.3).

I have followed this article https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/blob/main/docs/Firebase/CloudMessaging/GettingStarted.md for implementing firebase notifications on IOS.

I added APNs Authentication Key to firebase that i downloaded from my developer acc.

I added in my info.plist

- property FirebaseMessagingAutoInitEnabled -> No
- selected Enable Background Modes and selected Remote Notifications

In GoogleService-Info.plist Build Action -> Bundle Resource

- I have double checked my bundle_id, my project and in GoogleService-Info are the same.

In Entitlements.plist selected Remote Notifications

Here is my AppDelegate.cs

```
[Register("AppDelegate")]
public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate, IUNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, IMessagingDelegate
{
    private App app;

    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init();
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();

        DependencyService.Register<ILocalStorageManager, LocalStorageManager>();
        DependencyService.Register<ILauncherService, LauncherService>();

        LoadApplication(new App());

        Firebase.Core.App.Configure();
        // Register your app for remote notifications.
        if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(10, 0))
        {

            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = this;

            var authOptions = UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert | UNAuthorizationOptions.Badge | UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound;
            UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization(authOptions, (granted, error) => {
                Console.WriteLine(granted);
            });
        }
        else
        {
            // iOS 9 or before
            var allNotificationTypes = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound;
            var settings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(allNotificationTypes, null);
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(settings);
        }

        UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();



        Messaging.SharedInstance.Delegate = this;

        var token = Messaging.SharedInstance.FcmToken ?? "";
        Console.WriteLine($"FCM token: {token}");

        return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
    }

    [Export("messaging:didReceiveRegistrationToken:")]
    public void DidReceiveRegistrationToken(Messaging messaging, string fcmToken)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Firebase registration token: {fcmToken}");

        // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
        // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
    }

    public override void ReceivedRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo)
    {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification

        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        //Messaging.SharedInstance.AppDidReceiveMessage (userInfo);

        // Print full message.
        Console.WriteLine(userInfo);
    }

    public override void DidReceiveRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
    {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification

        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        //Messaging.SharedInstance.AppDidReceiveMessage (userInfo);

        // Print full message.
        Console.WriteLine(userInfo);

        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData);
    }

    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
    // Handle incoming notification messages while app is in the foreground.
    [Export("userNotificationCenter:willPresentNotification:withCompletionHandler:")]
    public void WillPresentNotification(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotification notification, Action<UNNotificationPresentationOptions> completionHandler)
    {
        var userInfo = notification.Request.Content.UserInfo;

        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        //Messaging.SharedInstance.AppDidReceiveMessage (userInfo);

        // Print full message.
        Console.WriteLine(userInfo);

        // Change this to your preferred presentation option
        completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.None);
    }

    // Handle notification messages after display notification is tapped by the user.
    [Export("userNotificationCenter:didReceiveNotificationResponse:withCompletionHandler:")]
    public void DidReceiveNotificationResponse(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotificationResponse response, Action completionHandler)
    {
        var userInfo = response.Notification.Request.Content.UserInfo;

        // Print full message.
        Console.WriteLine(userInfo);

        completionHandler();
    }
}}
```

In Console it generates my FCM token and when I try to send notification from Firebase Console nothing is printed in the console but it says its completed. Then I tried to sent it from postman and I received the next message.

```
{
"multicast_id": 5300302940762876386,
"success": 1,
"failure": 0,
"canonical_ids": 0,
"results": [
    {
        "message_id": "0:1627386458132596%db948e52db948e52"
    }
]}
```

My nugget packages IOS.CloudMessaging, IOS.Core, iOS.Installations and iOS.IstanceID are up todate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my problem.

I overrided FailedToRegisterForRemoteNotifications and saw that it throwed

> "no valid “aps-environment” entitlement string found for application"

and I checked that my bundle identifier in info.plist was ok, but in my xCode project was wrong and that solved my problem.