# Foundation You Should Not Call base In This Method

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have written code for Firebase Cloud Messaging in the Xamarin.IOS AppDelegates.cs file.

I am getting this exception message.

```
  Foundation.You_Should_Not_Call_base_In_This_Method
  Message=Exception of type 'Foundation.You_Should_Not_Call_base_In_This_Method' was thrown.
  Source=Xamarin.iOS
```

I'm getting an exception in this Override Method:

```
public override void FailedToRegisterForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSError error)
{
    base.FailedToRegisterForRemoteNotifications(application, error);
}
```

If I remove this method, the exception is not occurring and I'm receiving the token, but the problem is that notification is not occurring. From here, I am following the code [FCMSample.iOS](https://github.com/AnbuMani27/Xamarin-Forms-FCM-Notifications/blob/master/XF_FCM%20Notifications/FCMSample/FCMSample.iOS/AppDelegate.cs)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Did you search about this error message? You only need to delete `base.FailedToRegisterForRemoteNotifications(application, error);` in the method.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT are you really sure that in situations where a sign says *do not press this button or you get hurt* the solution to not get hurt is to not press the button? ;o) - yeah, I am joking

Comment: Yes, if I delete, then notification is not coming @LiyunZhang-MSFT

Comment: I still see an image of an error message in your post, which means you did not update it well enough. That error is a sentence written in text, which means there is no image needed at all to display it. Images should only be used when there is no other way to demonstrate an issue, such as a problem rendering an image or interface.

Comment: Yeh, I removed, please give me tips on how to fix it. Thank you @KenWhite

Comment: I think that's pretty clear. How is `You_Should_Not_Call_base_In_This_Method` unclear to you? You should not call base in that method, but should handle the details yourself in the code in that method.

Comment: Sorry for my vague expressions, op should write the code to do the job when the method called instead of calling the base method. @SirRufo

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT I was only joking - there was nothing vague to me

Comment: Actually, the notification should come even though you didn't call the base method.

Comment: Yes, Removed base method, and notification is going but not receiving  in ios device @LiyunZhang-MSFT

Comment: Did you receive the token?

Comment: Yes i receiving token @LiyunZhang-MSFT

Comment: According [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68544733/xamarin-ios-does-not-receive-firebase-notifications-but-registers-fcmtoken) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68544733/xamarin-ios-does-not-receive-firebase-notifications-but-registers-fcmtoken) which has the same problem. There may be something wrong in your info.plist.

Comment: I'm following from this [link](https://github.com/AnbuMani27/Xamarin-Forms-FCM-Notifications/blob/master/XF_FCM%20Notifications/FCMSample/FCMSample.iOS/AppDelegate.cs) @LiyunZhang-MSFT

Comment: Did you change the code in the info.plist according to your app? And you can refer to the accepted answer in the case about [How implement Push Notifications firebase xamarin.ios c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59984019/how-implement-push-notifications-firebase-xamarin-ios-c-sharp).

Comment: Yes it's looking all correct @LiyunZhang-MSFT

Comment: You can try to implement by following up the answer in the link I provided.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because person asking cannot read error messages

Comment: I tried all but notification is not occurring @LiyunZhang-MSFT